# Is there a way to add some sort of blacklist for the twitter streaming api?

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am currently using the Twitter streaming api with nodejs which has its basic parameters.

To filter my search, i can add the track parameter and add the list of words that I want.
I am looking for some kind of parameter or way to exclude words and that has the opposite purpose of the track parameter.
I might want to search the for the word "chocolate" but not "chocolate bar".

Answer (score 0):

While Twitter's API does not allow you to use a complex filter, you may as well filter whatever you get in a streaming way. Please check out an example I used on a conference presentation I made once on [on how to filter and classify tweets using node.js and scramjet](https://github.com/signicode/meetjs-luty).

Your code would be something like this (using Twit node module):

```
const stream = new DataStream();
new Twit(options)
    .on('tweet', (tweet) => stream.write(tweet));

return stream.filter(tweet => checkYourLogicAgains(tweet))
```

Depending on what you want to achieve you may run different filters or maps. The above mentioned example shows some more elaborate transforms.,

M.